# How to go about returning the status code from my ServiceHandler (Android JSON)

Tags: android, json, httprequest

I would like to get the status code from each httpResponse and handle the code differently from each response. However I am using a separate serviceHandler class below:

```
public class ServiceHandler {
static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {

}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                              List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        //get the Status code here
        int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();





    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}

}
```

How do I return the statusCode?

Here is my code that calls this and handles parsing the response:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String result = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);



        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + result);

        if (result != null) {
            try {

                NotValid = false;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            NotValid = true;


        }


        return null;


    }
```

Is it possible to parse the status code from the result above that is captured in my parser?

Answer (score 0):

create a class and put both status and response in it then return that class

```
class MyResult{
    public String response;
    public int statusCode;
}
```

and then your code must be something like this:

```
public class ServiceHandler {
static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {

}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public MyResult makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public MyResult makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                              List<NameValuePair> params) {
    MyResult result = new MyResult();
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        result.response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        //get the Status code here
        result.statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();





    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;

}

}
```

and finally in your asynctask:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        MyResult result = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + result);

    if (result.response != null) {
        try {

            NotValid = false;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        NotValid = true;


    }


    return null;


}
```

Comment: It almost works, I'm having an issue with putting the response and statusCode in the result class, the error is cannot resolve symbol 'response or statusCode' How would I fix this?

Comment: where did you declare `MyResult`? you can declare it in a separate class file and then import that class in each class you used for example import that in `ServiceHandler`

Comment: I've figured out an easier way although yours worked,  I'm handling the status code in the service handler class and depending on the code,  it will either change the response or leave it the same.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                          List<NameValuePair> params) {
try {
    String[] responseWithStatusCode=new String[2];
    // http client
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

    // Checking http request method type
    if (method == POST) {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        // adding post params
        if (params != null) {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        }

        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    } else if (method == GET) {
        // appending params to url
        if (params != null) {
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                    .format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
        }
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    }
    httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    //get the Status code here
    int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    //extra line
    responseWithStatusCode[0]=response;
    responseWithStatusCode[1]=Integer.parseInt(statusCode);



} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//return responseWithStatusCode instead of response....
return responseWithStatusCode;
```

}

and in your doBackground method:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // Creating service handler class instance
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    // changes in getting the return from makeServiceCall method
    String[] result = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + result);

if (result[1] != null && result[0].equalsIgnoreCase("200")) { // also change this line
    try {

        NotValid = false;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
} else {
    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    NotValid = true;


}


return null;
```

}